# Help with centering images

Tags: graphics

[image] I'm learning latex and I'm inserting 4 pictures like this:

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=]{name}
\end{center}
```

As you can see they are not centered, in the best manner.

Comment: It's difficult to see from a photo of a computer monitor (?) but my crystal ball tells me that inserting the images with a given scale just makes them too large for the page.

Comment: Add the line `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` to the preamble and put an fbox command around `\includegraphics`, i.e., `\fbox{\includegraphics{...}}`. This will show the amount of white space around your images that you may have to crop, as well as whether the image is too big for the page.

Comment: If you not use `geometry` package, than add the code line `\usepackage{showframe}` in preamble. With this you will see page layout and if image spill out of text border.

Comment: Don't insert your images, draw them using `TikZ`, it should be way more readable and doesn't seem too hard ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{name} % max. 1.00, I often use 0.8 for aesthetic reasons.
\end{center}
```

This way you make sure that the **picture width is not larger than the available text width**.